# On Windows 10, the add and remove programs dialogue is stuck on the last item making it impossible to use. How do I rectify?

Tags: windows-10, add-and-remove-programs

When I open the add and remove programs dialogue of system settings, the dialogue is unusable. It is unusable because as soon as I interact with the dialogue, it will select the last item on the list, and it is impossible to remove this selection.

Please see the following video because it's rather difficult to give a proper description of the behavior I am seeing.

https://imgur.com/a/kCeKMn3

Comment: I found pressing or holding the PageDown or Home keys will result in similar behavior (selects+scrolls to the last item). See if one of those keys, something like an fn+arrow key, or a mouse button is getting pressed/stuck?

Comment: As a workaround, it looks like you can still type into the search bar at the top of the apps list to filter by name (even if the view is scrolling, the bar stays selected). Then, if it scrolls to the end again, you'll still be on the right item.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks for taking a look. Clicking on the search bar also starts the behavior, so I can't seem to a cursor there to type anything. I tried a few times.

Comment: I disconnected all keyboards, and it doesn't rectify the issue. I agree this is consistent with the behavior, but it doesn't seem to be a 'hardware' issue. I'll also try another mouse, but I doubt that's it. I also checked some key event monitors and I don't see anything wonky there.

Comment: 1. Reboot, if you haven't. 2. Try Windows repair with SFC and DISM.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).